# SwiftUI layout issue with Vstack without giving child view a fix frame height

Tags: swiftui

I'm having issues trying to get my view to layout properly in the `VStack` when I add a `Text` view into the `PartnerCarouselView` `VStack`.

So, before adding the `Text` view, the code looks like this and it renders fine.

[image: ContentView]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let items = 1...10

    let rows = [
        GridItem()
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                PartnerCarouselView()
                PartnerCarouselView()
                PartnerCarouselView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PartnerCarouselView: View {

    let items = 1...10

    let rows = [
        GridItem()
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        PartnerCarouselItemView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PartnerCarouselView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PartnerCarouselView()
    }
}
```

However, when I update my `PartnerCarouselView` to include a `Text` view like below …

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title")
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        PartnerCarouselItemView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

… the whole view gets really messed up with views overlapping each other:

[image: overlapping view]

So far, I've understood that if I gave each of the view a fixed frame as below …

```
    VStack {
        Text("Title").frame(height: 21)
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: rows, alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    PartnerCarouselItemView()
                }
            }.frame(height: 350)
        }.frame(height: 350)
    }
```

… the view will layout fine. But I want my views to size dynamically, which is why I didn't provide any fixed height frame. Is there any way I can ensure all the child views in the `VStack` layout properly, without giving a fixed height frame?

Comment: Most probably the reason is in undefined height of PartnerCarouselItemView only. You have two scrollviews (in particular), so internal should be defined, otherwise how layout engine would decide where each view to place.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there no way around it, seems like it has to be defined no matter what

Comment: This question helped me solve a layout problem with a list and other view inside a VStack.  The other view was repeated with each list item until the OSX view was resized by dragging.  The problem was that the layout system couldn't determine the size of each list item.  Add a .frame(height: 125) and problem solved.